# Xubuntu долго выключается.

Tags: ubuntu

Xubuntu долго выключается. Долго вижу именно рабочий стол, все остальное нормально. Подскажите где можно посмотреть из-за чего это происходит, или может скажите решение :)

Answer (score 1):

Переключитесь в терминал, Ctrl-Alt-F1, например. Залогинтесь, дайте команду на выключение,  shutdown -h now  и наблюдайте на какой стадии висит.

Comment: да, можно ещё в скрипт шутдауна заглянуть. А так, на вскидку... а попробуйте посмотреть, правильно ли ДНС прописаны? очень часто проблема всех тормозов с демонами в linux-ах связаны с трудностями резолвинга

Comment: "скрипт шутдауна" это где? и где смотреть "правильно ли ДНС прописаны?" ну хоть примерный путь, или точное название фаликов, а я уже через locate поищу.

Comment: путь примерно такой (может ещё зависеть от дистрибутива линуха, я последнее время сидел на opensuse, потому и танцевать буду от него)- /etc/rcLEVEL.d/shutdown (что-то такое), точно не припомню уже к сожалению, а съюса под рукой нет. LEVEL в данном случае равен уровню запуска (в съюсе при обычной работе это 5). Пропись ДНС-сов можно проверить nslookup-ом, если отработает - то значит в порядке. Хотя сервисы в линухе могут использовать и что-либо своё (тут уж зависит от сервисов, кторые у вас работают), например в ssh проверку ДНС можно отключить так: UseDNS no в конфиге вместо UseDNS yes

Comment: нужно просто вкурить логи и посмотреть на какой задаче тормоза и копать туда...